# Generate multiples rows of new column based on one value of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a table like below:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 2022-03-21 |

I want to add a new column based on the date and it should look like this

| ID | Date | NewCol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-01 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-03-01 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-01 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-05-01 |
| 2 | 2022-03-21 | 2022-04-21 |
| 2 | 2022-03-21 | 2022-05-21 |

Let's say that there is a *@EndDate = 2022-05-31* (that's where it should stop)

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to do it in SSMS. Would appreciate any insights! Thanks :)

Comment: You need to explain the logic here.

Comment: You need to add all `Months` as dates between two Date values ?

Comment: What about 2022-01-31? What dates should be added? As there is no 2022-02-31, nor is there 2022-04-31.

Comment: If that was the case you can use `DATEADD(month, 1, dateColumn)`

Comment: so the logic would be I need a dates ONE MONTH from the Date value till the ENDDATE value. So for ID 1 I need the dates one month apart from 2022-01-01 till the @EndDate which is 2022-5-31 (its kinda like a loop for each ID)

Comment: @Aarlaneth we can use End of month in that case

Comment: @AnelHodžić It is kinda like a loop for every ID; The logic would be something like 

for every ID: DATEADD(month, 1, dateColumn) till 2022-05-31 (which could be a variable/parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with cal (id, dt) as 
(
               select id, date as dt from t
    union all  select id, dateadd(month, 1, dt) from cal where month(dt) < month('2022-05-31')
)

select   t.id
        ,t.date
        ,cal.dt as new_col
from     cal join t on t.id = cal.id and t.date != cal.dt
order by id, new_col
```

| id | date | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-01 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-03-01 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-01 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-05-01 |
| 2 | 2022-03-21 | 2022-04-21 |
| 2 | 2022-03-21 | 2022-05-21 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1pYY8HYT)

Answer (score 1):

In the following solutions we leverage string_split with combination with replicate to generate new records.

```
select    ID
         ,Date
         ,dateadd(month, row_number() over(partition by ID  order by (select null)), Date) as NewCol
from     (
         select   *
         from     t
         outer apply string_split(replicate(',',datediff(month, Date, '2022-05-31')-1),',')
         ) t
```

| ID | Date | NewCol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-01 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-03-01 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-01 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-05-01 |
| 2 | 2022-03-21 | 2022-04-21 |
| 2 | 2022-03-21 | 2022-05-21 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cBVv8-Bq)

For SQL in Azure and SQL Server 2022 we have a cleaner solution based on [ordinal][4].

> "The enable_ordinal argument and ordinal output column are currently
> supported in Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, and Azure
> Synapse Analytics (serverless SQL pool only). Beginning with SQL
> Server 2022 (16.x) Preview, the argument and output column are
> available in SQL Server."

```
select    ID
         ,Date
         ,dateadd(month, ordinal, Date) as NewCol
from     (
         select   *
         from     t
         outer apply string_split(replicate(',',datediff(month, Date, '2022-05-31')-1),',',1)
         ) t
```

Comment: this definitely works but I cannot use string_split since my compatibility level for the db is 100. Is there another way to achieve this? @DannySlor

Comment: Yes. I added another answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to "explode" a row into a set, the simplest in my opinion is a recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @endpoint date = '20220531';

DECLARE @prev date = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @endpoint);

WITH x AS
(
  SELECT ID, date, NewCol = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, date) FROM #d
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, date, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, NewCol) FROM x
    WHERE NewCol < @prev
)
SELECT * FROM x
  ORDER BY ID, NewCol;
```

Working example in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ht32ZMY3).

Keep in mind that if you could have > 100 months you'll need to add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION)` (or just consider using a different solution at scale).

Comment: I like this but the date values need to stay the same. Your solution also increments the date field by one for every row

Comment: @Sally sorry I missed that detail, try the edit.